# Jest Fetch API call unit test - unhandledpromiserejection error

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, fetch-api, unhandled-promise-rejection

I have a fetch call and unit test for that fetch all. It was working, suddenly i see that unit test cases failed for API unit testing. Below is my code

React fetch call

```
export const getUser = async () => {
  try {
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    return resp.json();
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```

Unit test case

```
const mockResp = {};
const mockJsonPromise = Promise.resolve(mockResp);
const mockFetchPromise = Promise.resolve({
  json: () => mockJsonPromise,
});

jest.spyOn(global, "fetch").mockImplementation(() => mockFetchPromise);

test("test getUser", (done) => {
  expect(getUser()).toEqual(mockFetchPromise);
  global.fetch.mockClear();
  done();
});
```

Error  - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with reason "Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'json')"